Sitefinity Precompiler in Azure Pipeline
I've ran into issues when trying to add the Sitefinity Precompiler to our Azure Pipeline.
What I've tried so far is to unzip the deployment package and run the "Precompiler\Telerik.Sitefinity.Compiler.exe".  It appears to be exiting with an error code of "4" which I understand to mean that there's an access issue.  I'm not sure what to change at this point to resolve that issue to get the DLLs to compile.  Am I approaching this the wrong way?
Additional Details:

Here is the YAML for the Run Precompiler step:
steps:
- script: |
   cd "SITE\Content\D_C\a\1\s\obj\release\Package\PackageTmp"
   
   Precompiler\Telerik.Sitefinity.Compiler.exe  /url="URL"  /authKey="***" /strategy="Frontend" /appdir="."
  displayName: 'Run Precompiler'

Finally, here is the error message (sadly, no more descriptive than previously shared):


Hi there, can you share your pipeline definition to let us know your workflow and the error message? Thx.

The changes I've implemented are in steps for our test release stage, so they don't seem to appear in the YAML for our pipeline.  Where would I find what you're requesting?
The error message is this when I run the command "Precompiler\Telerik.Sitefinity.Compiler.exe  /url="DomainOmitted"  /authKey="***" /strategy="Frontend" /appdir="."":
2024-09-27T15:31:38.1791633Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '4'.

Which step has incurred this error? Can you share some screenshots to help understand how this task was configured? Please add the error message in original post. Thx.

I've now added more details

Based on the update of your release pipeline definition, we could see in the script of the step Run Precompiler, the path to SITE\Content\D_C\a\1\s\obj\release\Package\PackageTmp\Precompiler\Telerik.Sitefinity.Compiler.exe didn't seem to be an valid path, and we don't know how you build pipeline published the artifacts files and the artifacts alias.
Usually, the release pipeline will download the artifacts files into the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) which is D:\a\r1\a on a Windows Microsoft-hosted agent machine.
Anyway, in all cases, you may add a CMD script in front of  Run Precompiler step to check if correct path to your app Telerik.Sitefinity.Compiler.exe like below, where I checked the artifacts path to my built console app in a release pipeline.
- script: |
    tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) /f /a
  displayName: 'Check artifacts path'



I have verified that this is the correct path and the EXE does run (I did mask part of the path with "SITE" for this case).  I ran the EXE without parameters and it reports back with the message (non error) that I need to include certain parameters.  It seems like the issues is permissions, based on writing the compiled dlls, but I can't say that for certain.

Are you running this EXE on Microsoft-hosted agent? Is the EXE file extracted by the Extract File step. Have you tried to extract those files into a new path and then run the EXE there?

I hadn't tried having it extract to a new path.  So, now I have tested it by extracting to "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/newtestdirectory" and I ran the executable in that directory, but it still returned an error of "4".

Is this app executable as soon as extracted? Can you have a test to download the artifacts and extract it to your local machine and run the same command to execute it? It the release pipeline running on a Windows MS-hosted agent by the way?

Yes, it's running on a Windows agent and it is executable as soon as it is extracted (I'm able to get messages that I'm missing parameters proving that it runs).  When I configure the command with the necessary parameters it does seem to run for awhile before it will finally return the error.  When I run the executable on my desktop, it runs for a very long time to compile the pages.

How long would it take to run on your desktop? Was this expected? Did it exceed your agent job timeout limit?

It can take 10 minutes or so to run on my desktop.  From what I'm reading this is finishing well under the default pipeline timeout (and the agent is set to 0 for timeout).

Is it possible to create a new release pipeline for a test, where you can consume that package and add only the two steps to extract and run script?
